# Combobox, BindingSource, WinForms - Adding new entry in one-to-many relation

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, bindingsource

I have company model in relation one-to-many with person model.
I want to add new Person and in combobox I want to be able to select company from companies, all using bindingsource. I have `PeopleForm` when I list all people and in this form I have add new Person button. In `PersonForm` I have text boxes and combobox with list of companies.
First I set bindingsources:

```
BindingList<Company> companiesList = new BindingList<Company>();
    private void PoepleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(Ctx ctx = new Ctx())
        {
            personBindingSource.DataSource = ctx.People.ToList();
            foreach (Company company in ctx.Companies)
            {
                companiesList.Add(company);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my button Add person event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PersonForm personForm = new PersonForm()
            {
                MdiParent = this.MdiParent,
                person = new Person(),
                companiesList = companiesList
            };

            personForm.FormClosing += delegate
            {
                if (personForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    using (Ctx ctx = new Ctx())
                    {
                        personBindingSource.Add(personForm.person);
                        ctx.People.Add(personForm.person);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                        personBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
                    }
                }
            };
            personForm.Show();
        }
```

PersonForm load event:

```
private void PersonForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personBindingSource.DataSource = person;
            companyBindingSource.DataSource = companiesList;
        }
```

Class Company:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NIP { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }

}
```

Class person:

```
public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {

        }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int Mobile { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

In PersonForm I have used designer to add textboxes, all of them have bindings set to personBindingSource. What sources should I set in combobox to have a company list in it and to have both elements (textboxes and combobox selected value) connected. I am trying to understand magic behind bindingsource.

Comment: YOU need to bind the combo box to a companyBindingSource, then set display member and value member. Also in the property window for combo box you need to set text binding to none

Comment: In combobox properies there is no text binding. All I can see is:
DataSource, DisplayMember, ValueMember and SelectedValue.
From my understanding `datasource` should be set to `companyBindingSource`, `DisplayMember` I set to `company.Name`, `ValueMember` is set to `company.Id` - and `SelectedValue` I set to `person.Company` - when I change items in combobox list my program freezes.

Comment: I am sorry, there is text binding and it is set to none anyway.

Comment: on form load event did you fill the dataset for Person and Company, using the tableadaptor?

Comment: I am not using table adapters. I set bindingsources data sourcs - I edited my post.

Comment: If `ValueMember` is `Id` of company, shouldn't the `SelectedValue` be transferred to something like `person.CompanyId`? (however it may be called, you didn't include your model classes!)

Comment: Added models code.

Comment: At least part of your problem should be the combination of `ValueMember` and expecting `SelectedValue` to be the whole company object. It would be better if you have an explicit foreign key property `Company_Id` in the EF model and use it to assign your selected value.

Comment: Yes, this made freeze my program. I added `CompanyId` to my model and it works. One more question. Now in `datagridview` I have list of people. I want to display name of company of each person. I quess I know what I need to do, but I was using designer and I don't know where I can change code of datagridview column so I can explicitly make that Company column to display not Company object nor CompanyId, but Company.Name. Any tips ??

Comment: No, I hardly ever worked with winforms, and have no idea how to do anything in the designer. I could only help with the other topic because the concepts of `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue` are a common approach that I know from other frameworks.

Comment: I have used combobox for my last column to display company name and it worked out. 
Thanks for help.